# ServiceNow Rest API call

Tags: rest, web-services, rest-client, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to use a between operator as below,

```
curl -k "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/My_Table?sysparm_query=sys_updated_on>javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2017-12-06','14:45:23')^sys_updated_on<javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2017-12-08','14:45:23')" --request GET --header "Accept:application/json" --user 'My Username':'My Password'
```

The output that I get is not in between the specified date Limit. Is there anything that I am doing wrong with the Command. Is the above command built correctly?I am stuck with this and trying different ways. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the BETWEEN query operator.

```
sysparm_query=sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2017-12-06','14:45:23')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2017-12-08','14:45:23')
```

You should then URL-encode the query to make sure none of your characters would cause an issue:

```
sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.dateGenerate(%272017-12-06%27%2C%2714%3A45%3A23%27)%40javascript%3Ags.dateGenerate(%272017-12-08%27%2C%2714%3A45%3A23%27)
```

Pro-tip: You can actually just go to the table and run the exact query you want to run, then right-click the query breadcrumb and click "Copy query" to get the exact query syntax you want.

More on this in my book: [Learning ServiceNow](http://lsn.sngeek.com). For a more advanced and shorter compendium of ServiceNow best-practices, pro-tips, and guidelines, check out my latest book: [The ServiceNow Development Handbook](http://handbook.sngeek.com).

Comment: Tim I have one doubt with this, What would be the Time Zone that ServiceNow use?

Comment: This generates times in GMT - the system time-zone.
Details on the gs.dateGenerate() API here: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-application-development/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/GlideSystem/concept/c_GlideSystemAPI.html#ariaid-title18
Info on handling time-zones in ServiceNow in my article, here: https://snprotips.com/blog/2017/9/12/handling-timezones-in-servicenow-timezoneutil

Comment: Thank you for your Response Tim.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark as correct if this helped you out.